# all benefits to use overlay

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, i want to know all benefits for using overlays in my home in my fuerte ? like in this link
http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Overlays

i am now using my home/ros stacks and linked it with ros core in /opt

1- what the benefits to made an overlay in my home and set my /home/ros stacks in it ?

2- I want to change somethings in a cpp code in packages,, should i give permissons to every file i want to change it's code ??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48973/all-benefits-to-use-overlay/) by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 464 on 2012-11-23

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

- You don't need to manually maintain the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
- You can easily add repositories from multiple different sources (git, svn, local, rosinstall, ...)
- Very easy setup of a new workspace from a larger projects rosinstall (in constrast to manually downloading/cloning/checking out of single code locations)
- You can run VCS commands for multiple different repository sources (rosws update/rosws status) instead of doing that for each
- You can have multiple workspaces for different projects, ros distros, etc. and switch between them easily

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on 2012-11-23**:
@dornhege  thanks alot ,, and i just use in my project anout 6 or 7 stacks ,,  was installed in my/home/ros and /home  .. i manually linked them with ROS in /opt using ROS_PACKAGE_PATH variable
it was easy to do this

**Comment by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on 2012-11-23**:
shoud i do overlay now and add my home stacks on it ? or if every stack work well with it's commands
i don't have to do overlay ?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-11-23**:
It's up to you, but recommended. I manage everything with rosws.

**Comment by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on 2012-11-23**:
yes, Thanks alot,, i'll try using it to see